# Tracking elapsed time for a set of Tasks

Tags: vb.net, timer, stopwatch, elapsedtime

I am trying to write a small VB.NET application to conduct a cross team time in motion study in work.  I need the ability to have multipul timers running for single tasks, and when a user has finished their tasks they can end it and it will be stored in a CSV file.  I can do it with single tasks at once, and this has been running for a while within the business.  What is the best method to have multipul tasks running at once.  I had the idea of adding the tasks to a listview and having double click event as the end task function.  However I can't seem to get the timers to run independantly. Can anyone help? Does this make sense?

This is the main bulk of the workload in this class.  If this doesnt make sense I appologise in advance.  I'm not a programmer by trade, it's just a side hobby which I am practising in work.

Another thing would be to have the elapsed seconds counting live, I can do this with a label but I would need an unlitmited amount of task in theory...

```
Public Class runningTask
    Dim timenow As DateTime = Now
    Dim elapsed
    Dim localTask = GlobalVars.task

    Public Sub AddItem()
        CreateTimer()

        Dim str(3) As String
        Dim itm As ListViewItem

        str(0) = localTask
        str(1) = timenow
        str(2) = elapsed

        itm = New ListViewItem(str)

        frmTime.lvTimers.Items.Add(itm)
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateTimer()
        Dim tmr As New Timer
        tmr.Interval = 1000
        tmr.Enabled = True
        AddHandler tmr.Tick, AddressOf GlobalTimerTick
    End Sub

    Private Sub GlobalTimerTick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim t As TimeSpan = Now - timenow
        elapsed = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}:{3:00}", Math.Floor(t.TotalHours), t.Minutes, t.Seconds, t.Milliseconds)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a more OOP approach which may be more economical as far as Timers, but has a very simple interface.  The core is a TaskItem which tracks the job and time, then a collection class to expose them, start them and stop them.  By burying as much functionality at as low of level as possible things get simpler.

I only used one timer and cant see why you'd need multiple timers for a single task.  If a TaskItem records the `DateTime` when it starts (this happens automatically when it is created in mine), then you don't need any Timers at all.  Elapsed is always calculated using `StartedTime`  and either `DateTime.Now` (for a running task) or `CompletedTime` for completed tasks. I cant see where a Timer adds anything.

You'll have to make many mods for your purposes.  This does not save completed items, nor remove them from the list, but may give you a place to start.  Its also a first-pass thing; there are surely issues here and there.

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class Tasks

    ' slight overkill
    Private Enum LVGroups
        Running
        Completed
    End Enum

    Public Enum TaskJobs
        SweepFloor
        BuildRobot
        CleanOven
        RepairRobot
        EmptyTrash
        TeachRobotToTalk
        MakeCoffee
        TeachRobotToWalk
        WashDishes
        TeachRobotVisualBasic
    End Enum

    ' class for a single task
    Public Class TaskItem
        ' these ought to be readonly; so no cheating
        Public Property ID As String
        Public Property EmpName As String

        Public Property StartedTime As DateTime
        Public Property CompletedTime As DateTime

        ' or job code...
        Public Property Job As TaskJobs

        ' put in a ClassLib or Namespace
        Friend Sub New(sName As String, tj As TaskJobs)
            EmpName = sName
            Job = tj

            StartedTime = DateTime.Now
            CompletedTime = DateTime.MaxValue
            ID = System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString
        End Sub

        Public Function IsActive() As Boolean
            Return (CompletedTime = DateTime.MaxValue)
        End Function

        Public Sub EndTask()
            CompletedTime = DateTime.Now
        End Sub

        Public Function GetElapsed() As String
            Dim t As TimeSpan
            If IsActive() Then
                t = DateTime.Now - StartedTime
            Else
                t = CompletedTime - StartedTime
            End If
            Return String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", Math.Floor(t.TotalHours),
                                                 t.Minutes, t.Seconds)
        End Function

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", EmpName, Job.ToString, GetElapsed)
        End Function

    End Class


    Private col As Collection(Of TaskItem)

    Private myLV As ListView

    ' assign the LV when tasks are created
    Public Sub New(lvTask As ListView)
        myLV = lvTask
        col = New Collection(Of TaskItem)
    End Sub

    ' add new task with EmpName and JobCode
    Public Sub NewTask(sName As String, tj As TaskJobs)

        Dim ti As New TaskItem(sName, tj)
        col.Add(ti)

        ' LV layout: empname, job, elapsed, ID
        ' but only 3 columns so that ID is "hidden"

        Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(ti.EmpName)
        lvi.SubItems.Add(ti.Job.ToString)
        lvi.SubItems.Add(ti.GetElapsed)
        lvi.SubItems.Add(ti.ID)

        lvi.Group = myLV.Groups(LVGroups.Running.ToString)
        myLV.Items.Add(lvi)

    End Sub

    ' called from dbl click on a running task item
    Public Sub StopTask(lvi As ListViewItem)

        Dim ti As TaskItem = (From t In col Where t.ID = lvi.SubItems(3).Text).First

        ' the form doesnt check the status, so we must
        If ti.IsActive Then
            ti.EndTask()
            lvi.Group = myLV.Groups(LVGroups.Completed.ToString)
        End If

    End Sub

    ' called from the form timer tick event
    Public Sub UpdateDisplay()
        Dim ti As TaskItem

        ' iterate items to get ID of runners
        For Each lvi As ListViewItem In myLV.Groups(LVGroups.Running.ToString).Items
            ' ToDo add error checking

            ti = (From t In col Where t.ID = lvi.SubItems(3).Text).First
            lvi.SubItems(2).Text = ti.GetElapsed

        Next

    End Sub

    Public Function RunnersCount() As Integer
        Return GetActiveList.Count
    End Function

    Public Function GetCompletedList() As List(Of TaskItem)
        ' long form
        Dim tList As New List(Of TaskItem)

        For Each ti As TaskItem In col
            If ti.IsActive = False Then
                tList.Add(ti)
            End If
        Next

        Return tList

        ' short form
        'Dim list = (From t In col Where t.IsActive = False).ToList
    End Function


    Public Function GetActiveList() As List(Of TaskItem)
        ' long form
        'Dim tList As New List(Of TaskItem)

        'For Each ti As TaskItem In col
        '    If ti.IsActive Then
        '        tList.Add(ti)
        '    End If
        'Next   
        'Return tList

        ' short form
        Dim list = (From t In col Where t.IsActive).ToList
        Return list

    End Function
End Class
```

Usage:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private myTasks As Tasks

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        myTasks = New Tasks(Me.lvTask)
        cboTask.Items.AddRange([Enum].GetNames(GetType(Tasks.TaskJobs)))
    End Sub
```

Add a task:

```
myTasks.NewTask(cboEmp.Text, CType(cboTask.SelectedIndex, Tasks.TaskJobs))
```

Stop a task:

```
' called from LV mousedoubleclick, so determine the item
Dim lvi As ListViewItem = lvTask.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y)
myTasks.StopTask(lvi)
```

Obviously, stopping a task might automatically append the data to the export file.  That functionality would be in the Task Collection Class, where it would be done just before the task is removed from the collection (optional - they arent hurting any thing there as long as you can tell active from completed ones).

Timer Tick event:

```
    myTasks.UpdateDisplay()
```

[image]

Finally, turn on `Option Strict` especially since people will be making decisions based on the project's output.

Comment: Thanks, I actually got this working in the end.  I was using a DataGridView and looped through the rows on the tick event of my timer.  Works perfectly, I wish I'd remembered to check the answers as your solution is very good.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: glad to help - the control (LV vs DGV) doesnt matter since the principle is the same.  and it is never too late to accept/check an answer when they help.

Comment: Thanks! All working now and submitting to sharepoint for reporting.